# I want tinymce NOT readonly

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

As the opposite of all the post I found, I have an instance of TinyMCE that is readonly on Chrome and IE for one of my client.  It only works on firefox.  When he open the demo on tinymce website, it works.  So I suppose the problem is something in my initialize but I don't want to remove all for one client.

My problem is I can't figure why that happend on his computer, I've tried without JS enabled,cookie, etc.. but always work on my computer.  Did someone experienced that problem with tinymce of a case where you can't edit the text even if you set nothing on readonly.

There is my code, and I repeat that I can just try removing option to find the problem because I have no access to the computer experiencing the problem but I had someone I know confirming the issue.  If you have an idea feel free to help me :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea", 
                    plugins: [
                        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages emoticons textcolor visualchars "
                    ],      
        theme: "modern",
        remove_script_host : false,
        relative_urls: false,       
        convert_fonts_to_spans: true,
        content_css : "custom_content.css",
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",        
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",      
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | fontselect | fontsize | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
        { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
        { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
    ],
    language : "fr_FR"
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: tried adding readonly : false ?

Comment: isn't trextarea disabled?

Comment: I tried the readonly false and textarea wasn't disabled.  But the cursor didn't show up on my computer even if I can write inside.  It is like there is a frame over the text but when I click on item on the menu the cursor come back.  But I found that the version of tinyMCE wasn't the latest even if I got it last month.  I tried to update and I seem to be working better now, the cursor always show itself.  I asked my client to do test and I'll give you the answer, if it's a version issue.  Thanks for your reply by the way :)